# Cannot resolve Artifact by Build Number or LATEST when copied to another repository

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

We are having difficulties with our use of the *Artifactory Plug-in for Jenkins* when specifying **Resolution Details | Resolved Artifacts (requires Artifactory Pro)** (I will refer to this value as the *Artifactory-query-string*).

Our use of Artifactory in this case is to pull an existing module (a single ZIP file in Artifactory), and we wish to retrieve that specific module with a *specific build number* or the abstract request for '*LATEST*' build.

We can get the result that we want when the module / artifact that we want exists in only one repository.  But after a given BUILD # of a module has been 'promoted' (via simple copy operation in Artifactory) then we are not able to find the 'promoted' artifact in the Repository it was copied to.

#### Tools / Versions

- Jenkins (2.7.2)
- Artifactory Pro (4.11.2)
- Artifactory Plug-in for Jenkins (2.6.0)
- Generic Package Type with the 'simple-default' layout in Artifactory

#### Background

Recently we have introduced the Jenkins Build # as both a property for the artifact and as part of the artifact file name.

The only source of information that we have been able to find with details about this 'Artifactory-query-string' is via the Help information available via the Question Mark icon located next to the input area.

Our interpretation of this Help text indicates:

- If one wants to retrieve by **build_number** (or 'LATEST') then the **build_name** value MUST also be specified, in other words these two values are mutually dependent

### Working Case

When using this capability in this manner (in one repository only - called **DEV**), everything works as expected.  We are able to successfully fill a request for 'LATEST' or a specific Build Number using the **build_number** parameter, as long as we also specify the **build_name**.

*Artifactory tree*

- **DEV** (repository)

  - **somePath** (path)

    - **myApplication-build-100.zip**       build_number: **100**   build_name: **myJenkinsBuildJob**
    - **myApplication-build-101.zip**       build_number: **101**   build_name: **myJenkinsBuildJob**
    - **myApplication-build-102.zip**       build_number: **102**   build_name: **myJenkinsBuildJob**

*Artifactory-query-string*
`$DEV:somePath/myApplication*.zip@myJenkinsBuildJob#$LATEST=>.\someFolder`

This *Artifactory-query-string* will properly return the single artifact: `myApplication-build-102.zip`

### Failing Case

However after one of these builds is 'promoted' to another repository such as **QA** via a simple COPY operation in Artifactory, we cannot figure out how to leverage this same capability against the **QA** repository where the artifact was just copied ('promoted').  In other words, we cannot 'find' the copied / 'promoted' artifact in the repository where it was copied to.

*Artifactory tree*

- **DEV** (repository)

  - **somePath** (path)

    - **myApplication-build-100.zip**       build_number: **100**   build_name: **myJenkinsBuildJob**
    - **myApplication-build-101.zip**       build_number: **101**   build_name: **myJenkinsBuildJob**
    - **myApplication-build-102.zip**       build_number: **102**   build_name: **myJenkinsBuildJob**
- **QA** (repository)

  - **somePath** (path)

    - **myApplication-build-102.zip**       build_number: **102**   build_name: **myJenkinsBuildJob** (copied / 'promoted' from DEV repository)

*Artifactory-query-string*
Using the same 'Artifactory-query-string' as before but specifying the **QA** repository rather than **DEV**

`$QA:somePath/myApplication*.zip@myJenkinsBuildJob#$LATEST=>.\someFolder`

then the Artifactory plug-in for Jenkins never returns / finds anything:

```
Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version: 2.6.0
Beginning to resolve Build Info dependencies.
Finished resolving Build Info dependencies.
Beginning to resolve Build Info build dependencies.
Dependency on build [myJenkinsBuildJob], number [LATEST], pattern [QA:somePath/myApplication*.zip] - [0] results found.
```

An interesting note is that if we delete the original artifact in the **DEV** repository, then the query against **QA** works correctly.

The observed behavior seems to suggest that a given artifact (based on the filename, build # and build name) can only be located / queried (resolved) in one repository and that if you copy an artifact to another repository it will be 'hidden' or ignored for such a query.

This is not the behavior that we expected.  We expected that each repository is separate from the others and that a query against one repository should NOT take into account anything about any other repositories -- and that we should be able to locate / find / resolve a copied module in the repository it was copied to.

Can anyone suggest what am I missing here?  Are my expectations wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-9343) with build info as it references artifacts by checksum only. If you move the artifacts rather than copy them, it will resolve from the correct path.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Thank you for your answer -- this is an item that I had not managed to find.  If no one else posts anything more enlightening, I will give you the Accept later today.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 2.9.0 of Jenkins Artifactory plugin, [file specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-DownloadSpecSchema) supports [retrieving artifacts by build](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-865).
 
In this new implementation your scenario works.

Your download spec should look as following:

```
{
  "files": [    
    {
      "pattern": "${QA}/somePath/myApplication*.zip",
      "target": "someFolder/",
      "build" : "myJenkinsBuildJob/LATEST",
      "flat": "false",
      "recursive": "true"
    }
  ]
}
```